# Why is objective-c rounding down when it comes to division of double data types?

Tags: objective-c

Why does `NSLog(@"%0.0f", 1.0/10.0);` output 0?

Isn't `1.0/10.0` division of two double values? Why is it rounding down to 0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you're asking it to print 0 decimal places with your format specifier.

```
NSLog(@"%f", 1.0/10.0);
```

> 0.100000

[printf specs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/printf.html):

> - An optional precision that gives the ... number of digits to appear after the radix character [in this case, the decimal point in the output - JC] for the a, A, e, E, f, and F conversion specifiers... The precision takes the form of a period ( '.' ) followed either by an asterisk ( '*' ), described below, or an optional decimal digit string, where a null digit string is treated as zero.